Problem with update-alternatives and cpp after updating to 22.04
After updating from 20.04 LTS to 22.04 LTS, everything appears to be working fine, except if I run sudo apt upgrade I get the following issue:
Setting up cpp (4:11.2.0-1ubuntu1) ...
update-alternatives: error: alternative path /usr/bin/cpp doesn't exist
dpkg: error processing package cpp (--configure):
 installed cpp package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit s
tatus 2

I suspect the problem is that while on 20.04, I had set up a particular master-slave relationship between gcc and cpp using update-alternatives while trying to install some CUDA libraries.
Any attempt to reinstall gcc, g++, cpp etc results in the same error as above. In fact, pretty much any command to do with apt ends up with the above error.
Not sure if relevant, but if I run update-alternatives --get-selections, I get the following:
animate                        auto     /usr/bin/animate-im6.q16
animate-im6                    auto     /usr/bin/animate-im6.q16
arptables                      auto     /usr/sbin/arptables-nft
awk                            auto     /usr/bin/mawk
bibtex                         auto     /usr/bin/bibtex.original
builtins.7.gz                  auto     /usr/share/man/man7/bash-builtins.7.gz
c++                            auto     /usr/bin/g++
c89                            auto     /usr/bin/c89-gcc
c99                            auto     /usr/bin/c99-gcc
cc                             auto     /usr/bin/gcc
compare                        auto     /usr/bin/compare-im6.q16
compare-im6                    auto     /usr/bin/compare-im6.q16
composite                      auto     /usr/bin/composite-im6.q16
composite-im6                  auto     /usr/bin/composite-im6.q16
conjure                        auto     /usr/bin/conjure-im6.q16
conjure-im6                    auto     /usr/bin/conjure-im6.q16
convert                        auto     /usr/bin/convert-im6.q16
convert-im6                    auto     /usr/bin/convert-im6.q16
csh                            auto     /bin/bsd-csh
default.plymouth               auto     /usr/share/plymouth/themes/bgrt/bgrt.plymouth
display                        auto     /usr/bin/display-im6.q16
display-im6                    auto     /usr/bin/display-im6.q16
ebtables                       auto     /usr/sbin/ebtables-nft
editor                         auto     /bin/nano
ex                             auto     /usr/bin/vim.tiny
fakeroot                       auto     /usr/bin/fakeroot-sysv
ftp                            auto     /usr/bin/tnftp
futurize                       auto     /usr/bin/python3-futurize
gdm-theme.gresource            auto     /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/Yaru/gnome-shell-theme.gresource
gnome-text-editor              auto     /usr/bin/gedit
gnome-www-browser              auto     /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable
gnuplot                        auto     /usr/bin/gnuplot-qt
google-chrome                  auto     /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable
gstreamer-codec-install        auto     /usr/libexec/pk-gstreamer-install
identify                       auto     /usr/bin/identify-im6.q16
identify-im6                   auto     /usr/bin/identify-im6.q16
import                         auto     /usr/bin/import-im6.q16
import-im6                     auto     /usr/bin/import-im6.q16
infobrowser                    auto     /usr/bin/info
ip6tables                      auto     /usr/sbin/ip6tables-nft
iptables                       auto     /usr/sbin/iptables-nft
java                           auto     /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
jexec                          auto     /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/lib/jexec
jjs                            auto     /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/jjs
keytool                        auto     /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/keytool
libblas.so.3-x86_64-linux-gnu  auto     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3
liblapack.so.3-x86_64-linux-gnu auto     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3
libpsm_infinipath.so.1         auto     /usr/lib/libpsm1/libpsm_infinipath.so.1.16
lzma                           auto     /usr/bin/xz
mogrify                        auto     /usr/bin/mogrify-im6.q16
mogrify-im6                    auto     /usr/bin/mogrify-im6.q16
montage                        auto     /usr/bin/montage-im6.q16
montage-im6                    auto     /usr/bin/montage-im6.q16
mt                             auto     /bin/mt-gnu
nc                             auto     /bin/nc.openbsd
newt-palette                   auto     /etc/newt/palette.ubuntu
open                           auto     /usr/bin/xdg-open
orbd                           auto     /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/orbd
pack200                        auto     /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/pack200
pager                          auto     /usr/bin/less
pasteurize                     auto     /usr/bin/python3-pasteurize
pbr                            auto     /usr/bin/python3-pbr
pico                           auto     /bin/nano
pinentry                       auto     /usr/bin/pinentry-gnome3
pinentry-x11                   auto     /usr/bin/pinentry-gnome3
policytool                     auto     /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/policytool
rcp                            auto     /usr/bin/scp
rlogin                         auto     /usr/bin/slogin
rmid                           auto     /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/rmid
rmiregistry                    auto     /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/rmiregistry
rmt                            auto     /usr/sbin/rmt-tar
rsh                            auto     /usr/bin/ssh
rview                          auto     /usr/bin/vim.tiny
servertool                     auto     /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/servertool
shimx64.efi.signed             auto     /usr/lib/shim/shimx64.efi.signed.latest
stream                         auto     /usr/bin/stream-im6.q16
stream-im6                     auto     /usr/bin/stream-im6.q16
telnet                         auto     /usr/bin/telnet.netkit
text.plymouth                  auto     /usr/share/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-text/ubuntu-text.plymouth
tnameserv                      auto     /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/tnameserv
unit2                          auto     /usr/bin/python3-unit2
unpack200                      auto     /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/unpack200
vi                             auto     /usr/bin/vim.tiny
view                           auto     /usr/bin/vim.tiny
vtrgb                          auto     /etc/console-setup/vtrgb
which                          auto     /usr/bin/which.debianutils
write                          auto     /usr/bin/write.ul
x-cursor-theme                 auto     /usr/share/icons/DMZ-White/cursor.theme
xdvi.bin                       auto     /usr/bin/xdvi-xaw
x-session-manager              auto     /usr/bin/gnome-session
x-terminal-emulator            auto     /usr/bin/gnome-terminal.wrapper
x-window-manager               auto     /usr/bin/mutter
x-www-browser                  auto     /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable


Worked it out!
I read up more on exactly how update-alternatives works, as well as the difference between c++ and cpp and it became clear to me that the output of update-alternatives --get-selections should contain a line for cpp. So I navigated to /usr/bin and ran ls and sure enough I had cpp-9, cpp-10, cpp-11, and cpp-12 in there. So then all it took was to create the appropriate entry using:
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/cpp cpp /usr/bin/cpp-11 1

sudo apt upgrade now runs to completion with no errors.
Thanks to a commenter for pointing out that cpp-11 is the default for Ubuntu 22.04.

There are other ways to use the gcc,ccp,g++,... versions a CUDA install requires without changing the system defaults. Just put the necessary tool versions into the cuda/bin  cuda/lib dirs, and the normal PATH change will pick them up for you.  The next time update needs cpp-11, things may break, and that's not going to be update's fault.

@ubfan1 Fair enough. I do believe at the time I was following instructions in an upvoted answer on Ask Ubuntu, but admittedly, I'm having a hard time locating that question now. Just to be clear that I understand your comment, are you saying that cpp-11 is the default, and that I should have that as my entry in update-alternatives? I'll change the answer to reflect this so other viewers don't shift from non-default values.

11.4 is the default compiler for Ubuntu 22.04. update-alternatives has entries for cpp->/bin/cpp, cc->/bin/gcc and c++->/bin/g++, but nothing for cpp-11, gcc, or g++.  Likewise, nothing for python, too much in the system depends upon a specific  version.

@ubfan1 Thanks for responding. My understanding of what you are saying is that I should have had a default /bin/cpp on my system already, so why would I need to link cpp to cpp-11. Is this correct? If so, then my issue is that I did not have a /bin/cpp on my system at all, until I created it using the --install line in my answer above. I wondered if perhaps I had accidentally deleted an essential file somehow, so I reinstalled build-essential, but that didn't appear to change anything.

Yes. I think for 22.04, gcc is part of the initial install, so cpp is a dependency that gets automatically brought in and the /bin/cpp->cpp-11 link gets set up. Looks like 24.04 doesn't automatically bring in gcc, so no cpp either until you do the gcc install. Not sure what happens for updates from 20.04.

@ubfan1 Understood. Thanks again for the advice.
